# Ubuntu 14.04 Chromium Flash Plugin

Tags: apt, software-center, flash, chromium

---

UPDATE: Solution?

I installed Chrome:

https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Download the version for your system and install.  Flash worked right out of the box.  Much simpler than mucking around with plugins.

---

I realize this question is and has been asked a number of times around the web,  but the proposed solutions are not working for me.

Here is what I have tried:

- adobe flash plugin from the software center
- Downloading the software directly from the adobe website and installing

  > - First I downloaded the tar.gz file, I extracted it, and I installed according to the readme
  > - Second I downloaded the APT file, and I used the software center to install it.
- Pepper Flash Plugin: pepperflashplugin-nonfree

For all these options I was able to get them to run and install, ( Sometimes I had to install various dependencies. ) .

Regardless of method chromium fails to load flash content. Can anyone provide some insight?

And a Follow Up: Why is this such an issue?

It seems there are quite a number of people with this issue, yet there does not appear to be a consensus on how to solve it; there are almost as many proposed solutions as there are people asking about it.  Can a consensus be reached and a best practice be established?

Comment: Care to elaborate?  Does it need to be enabled?  If so, how?

Comment: Okay, I am reading the link you sent me to.  It is explaining the basics of native client, which I gather is a sandboxing utility for running non-native plugin content.

To be quite frank, I am seeking a solution to the issue of running flash content in chrome.  If it truly is the case that I need to dig into the details of browser sandboxing technology in order to play flash in chromium, then I may choose to seek an alternate solution entirely.

Comment: https://www.dhs.state.il.us/accessibility/tests/flash/video.html Try playing This video on your Chromium!

Comment: Yes, I have been going there.  It displays a grey screen saying, "Please install or enable Adobe Flash Player to view this content".

Comment: Your statement that chromium has 'Built-in' support for flash seems dubious at best, judging by the number of people who are having trouble viewing flash in chromium.

Comment: Aha! Thank you Sagar!  I feel this will work, though I haven't tested it yet.  I  didn't realize I could simply install chrome.

Comment: You have to run `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: Well, I had already done that.  Chrome played flash content right out of the box.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To install flash plugin, run following commad

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

For Chromium. follow, [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash) wiki, if above command dosen't work.

[Or, **download and install `Google chrome`**](https://www.google.com/chrome/)